# What is a more pleasant way of saying 'disorganized'?

Tags: single-word-requests

I've searched thesauruses to no avail. I'm hoping to find a more refined way of describing someone as 'disorganized', which to me seems to have a slightly negative connotation. The alternatives I have come across so far seem to be even worse ('chaotic', 'confused' etc.). What I have in mind would be something to conjure up the image of an eccentric scholar, perhaps sort of besieged by books piled on either side in disarray.

The question already posted didn't quite give me what I wanted, since it seemed to be referring to someone who was fond of chaos, not someone who simply can't keep themselves neat. I felt the suggestions given were mostly unflattering as well, which isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: Maybe untidy...?

Comment: I think that's a good improvement, but still not quite as euphemistic as the word I'm looking for. @FumbleFingers I also edited my post to differentiate it from the other question.

Comment: I suppose 'eclectic' might be useful to you...it is sometimes used in the way I think you intend, as a deliberate euphemism for disorganized.

Comment: I don't understand your "clarification". On the one hand you dismiss the "original" on the grounds that the question asks about someone who *like* chaos (implying that in *their* opinion, at least, being disorganised is a *good* thing). On the other hand you dismiss the answers there on the grounds that they're "unflattering" (i.e. - they imply the trait is a *bad* thing). But I'd have thought between the 20 answers there (several of which suggest more than one term) you should have almost all possibilities, regardless of the exact nuance you seek (which as I say, isn't clear to me).

Comment: *Absent-minded* or *scatty*?

Comment: **Bohemian** or **dilettante** ? *a dilletante is a person not deeply engaged in or concerned with something, who takes up an art, activity, or subject merely for amusement, especially in a desultory or superficial way*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Unfortunately all of the answers did have the implication that, for an observer, the trait was a bad thing. This was alright for that question because, as you said, the person in question might still think it a good thing. What I'm asking for is a word that has the trait being a good thing for an observer. The person actually might wish they were more organized, or not. I hope this explains it a bit more.

Thanks for all the helpful answers! So far eclectic seems to be the closest, although it is a rather cumbersome word to throw around.

Comment: *Mischievious, spontaneous, Dadaist,* for example don't strike me as particularly negative descriptions. But if you think *eclectic* seems to be close, I'm even more unsure of exactly what nuance you seek. If a thing or person is "eclectic", that just means they take input from a variety of sources (but they may make a very good job of *organising* those different components)

Comment: In this context, "*Jack-of-all-trades*" seems quite close to "eclectic".

Comment: In what sense disorganized?  Alan Guth (physics prof at MIT) won a prize for the messiest office in either Cambridge (or perhaps the Boston area, I don't remember which).  But his thinking is far from disorganized.

Comment: There is a term that will help you: **Executive function**.  There are a few different ways of using it, e.g. So-and-So has some executive function deficits, but that can be compensated by a good secretary.  You'll be very pleased with his creativity and commitment.

Comment: A relevant article: http://www.minnpost.com/second-opinion/2013/08/keep-messy-desk-u-study-finds-chaotic-clutter-may-promote-creativity

Comment: chaotic,
    confused,
    haphazard, 
    muddled,
    disordered,
    jumbled, 
    shuffled,
    disorderly,
    mixed up, 

    screwed up,
    unsystematic.

Comment: unmethodical, careless, inefficient, sloppy, lax, undisciplined, slapdash, remiss.

Comment: "What I have in mind would be something to conjure up the image of an eccentric scholar, perhaps sort of **besieged** by books piled on either side **in disarray**." Your own explanation of what you want uses *two* negative words. How do you expect anyone to come up with a single neutral word if you can't even explain it using neutral words!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking you can search for a negative connotation of one who is overly tidy, and then negate that word or phrase to create something that sounds more positive for a person who is apathetic about tidiness. Something like

> **unfussy** - not [excessively busy with trifles anxious or particular about petty details](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/unfussy?s=t)

Alternatively, a descriptive phrase that keeps coming back to me is one whose scholastic *preoccupation overflows* from mind to desk.  Perhaps synonyms for **unrestrained** may give you more ideas?

Answer (score 1):

*discombobulated* is a favorite of mine.

Answer (score 0):

Some images come to mind, changing disorganized to somewhat organized:

a scholar holed up in a bunker of books -- hunkered down

a scholar plowing through piles of books -- furrowing

a scholar in a feast of ideas, consuming piles of books -- digesting